# How to see the default values in a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

SQL> alter table dept modify (deptno number(2) default 10);
how to find out whether a column in a table contains a default value or not.how to see the default values in a table in oracle

Comment: you can see it on the oracle data dictionary views. create a select joining all_tables with all_tab_columns the default is on this last.

Answer (score 2):

Use the metadata table ALL_TAB_COLUMNS (or USER_TAB_COLUMNS if the table in question is on your current schema):

```
select DATA_DEFAULT
from all_tab_columns
where table_name='xxx' and column_name='yyy'
```